# form value 00:00:00 into time value

Tags: php, sql, time

I was wondering, if I record a time through a javascript function and say I leave it on for 2 mins 20 seconds:

```
00.02.20
```

now when I insert this into my database, where the field type is set as time, it doesn't record properly.

I think it comes from how I request the data:

```
$length = mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['timeDrive']);
```

is there a way of converting this into a time that is going to output the exact value:

```
00.02.20
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to perform any mathematical functions on those fields (eg: sum, average, etc), and it's purely for display, then you can just store it as plain text in a `CHAR(8)` field.

Otherwise, you'll need to normalise it to some sort of unit. I'd suggest maybe as an integer of the total number of seconds (if that is accurate enough for you).

To convert to seconds:

```
 $val = "00.02.20";
 $parts = explode(".", $val);   // ['00', '02', '20']
 $totalSeconds = parts[0] * 3600 + parts[1] * 60 + parts[2]; // 140
```

And to convert it back:

```
$seconds = 140; // this would be read from the database, or something

printf("%02d.%02d.%02d",
    $seconds / 3600,
    ($seconds / 60) % 60,
    $seconds % 60
);
```

Comment: I'm kind of with you, but I really need to insert it into the database as it is written (00:02:20) as I am peforming some sum() functions on existing time values.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, not just like this.

It would be possible, if you make it just more simple and you just count the number of seconds in javascript. In your Database you can save it as integer or something.

The other way is you save it just as string, but then you can't compare the times.

Well, I'd save it as an integer, and if you want to show the time to somebody, you would have to format it before, like this:

```
function formatTime($seconds) {
    $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);        //by nickf
    $minutes = floor($seconds / 60) % 60; 
    $sec = $seconds % 60;
    $retHr = (strlen($hours) == 1 ? "0" . $hours : $minutes);
    $retMin = (strlen($minutes) == 1 ? "0" . $minutes : $minutes);
    $retsec = (strlen($sec) == 1 ? "0" . $sec : $sec);
    return $retHr . "." . $retMin . "." . $retsec;
}

//now you counted one hour, two minutes and three seconds, you call it like 
echo formatTime(3723);
//... and it outputs "01.02.03"
```

Comment: Hell, you're right .... well I'll just change it, thanks for hint... I'm a newbie now for two years :P

Comment: Ok so I'm just a bit confused as to what is happening to the time string that I request... is it changed to a different number and then inserted? and if so how do I represent it back on the website as the form it was recorded in (00:02:20)

Comment: You don't request a time string, but an integer with the number of seconds. And on the site where you record it, just count the number of seconds instead generating such a format.
If you really request your time as-is as a string, then you should save it as a string in your database, this would be just the simplest way.